# Counting off the end of a string

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void testBlankPositionTooFar() {
    assertEquals(-1, sc1.blankPosition(4));
}
```

I am trying to get the string to count the number of blanks within the string and return the corresponding positions of the blanks. It's returning the correct positions of the blanks but now I need it to return a value = (-1) when it counts of the end of the string.

```
public int blankPosition(int blankNum) {
    int position = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < sentence.length()) {
        if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            position++;
            if ((position == blankNum)) 
                return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if `i` is equal to the length of the `String` - 1 (If it is at the end) and return -1 if it is, or `i` otherwise:

```
return i == sentence.length()-1 ? -1 : i;
```

Comment: I was really overthinking this problem. Thank you!                                                 if (i == sentence.length() - 1)
          return -1;